# ¿Cómo puedo corregir esta consulta para una tabla pivote en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Intento hacer una tabla pivote en MySQL utilizando como base la siguiente tabla llamada "lab_user_scores":

```
+------------+------------+---------+-------+
| id_problem | subproblem | id_user | score |
+------------+------------+---------+-------+
|          1 |          1 | Bob     |    15 |
|          1 |          2 | Bob     |    20 |
|          2 |          1 | Bob     |    40 |
|          2 |          2 | Bob     |    25 |
|          1 |          1 | Alice   |     5 |
+------------+------------+---------+-------+
```

Mi idea es tener una tabla como la siguiente:

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
| id_user | (1, 1) | (1, 2) | (2, 1) | (2, 2) | total_score |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
| Alice   |     15 |     20 |     40 |     25 |         100 |
| Bob     |      5 |      0 |      0 |      0 |           5 |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
```

Tengo el siguiente código en SQL:

```
SELECT 
id_user,
CASE WHEN id_problem = 1 AND subproblem = 1 THEN score ELSE 0 END AS "(1, 1)",
CASE WHEN id_problem = 1 AND subproblem = 2 THEN score ELSE 0 END AS "(1, 2)",
CASE WHEN id_problem = 2 AND subproblem = 1 THEN score ELSE 0 END AS "(2, 1)",
CASE WHEN id_problem = 2 AND subproblem = 2 THEN score ELSE 0 END AS "(2, 2)",
SUM(score) AS total_score
FROM lab_user_scores GROUP BY id_user
```

Ejecutando la sentencia anterior, obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
| id_user  | (1, 1) | (1, 2) | (2, 1) | (2, 2) | total_score |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
| Alice    |     15 |      0 |      0 |      0 |         100 |
| Bob      |      5 |      0 |      0 |      0 |           5 |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
```

Agradecería si alguien pudiera proveerme alguna orientación, de antemano, ¡gracias!

Comment: Agregación condicional: `sum(CASE WHEN id_problem = 2 AND subproblem = 2 THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS "(2, 2)"`

Comment: Si, en realidad a todo los case les hace falta un `SUM`

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Antes de ver estas respuestas lo había probado con MAX y también me entrega el mismo resultado. A simple vista pienso que SUM y MAX es lo mismo, ya que cada registro de mi tabla es único, pero técnicamente no sé cuál sería más apropiado con respecto a optimización.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar subconsultas por ejemplo:

```
select 
    lab.id_user ,
    (select sum(score) from lab_user_scores where id_user=lab.id_user and id_problem=1 and subproblem=1) '(1,1)',
    (select sum(score) from lab_user_scores where id_user=lab.id_user and id_problem=1 and subproblem=2) '(1,2)',
    (select sum(score) from lab_user_scores where id_user=lab.id_user and id_problem=2 and subproblem=1) '(2,1)',
    (select sum(score) from lab_user_scores where id_user=lab.id_user and id_problem=2 and subproblem=2) '(2,2)'
from lab_user_scores lab
group by lab.id_user ;
```

Comment: Hola @kllmp gracias por tu aporte. Una duda, ¿crees que podría ser más óptima tu consulta en vez de la que tengo? La tabla que tengo llegará a tener miles de registros.